# what is use of C_str() function in C/C++

Tags: c++, stdstring, c-str

Can anybody tell me what is the use of c_str() function in C/C++?.
In which case it is necessary to use it?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a C++ thing, not a C one.

A common use of [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) (from `std::string`) is precisely to convert a C++ `std::string` to a `const char*` C string, which is required by many many low level C functions (e.g. Posix system calls like `stat`, etc).

Answer (score 6):

When you want to use your string with C-functions

```
string s = "hello";
printf( "your string:%s", s.c_str() );
```

Answer (score 1):

> Generates a null-terminated sequence of characters (c-string) with the same content as the string object and returns it as a pointer to an array of characters.

There is a good example of its use here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're asking about `string::c_str()`?  It's a method that returns a C string representation of the `string` object.  You might need a C string representation to call an OS API, for example.